# Please make deleted post on reputation page linkified!

Tags: feature-request, reputation, profile-page

I had just deleted [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123800/155556).

So my [reputation page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155556/amanap-lanac-a-nalp-a-nam-a?tab=reputation) now reflects that.

### But

For some reason the row that tells me of the deletion does not have a link to my deleted answer.

Can we please make it so that text is linkified as well?

[image: linkify it]

Comment: I *think* this is [on purpose](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes#comment328892_123330).  Although I'm remembering some mixed messages about this topic, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Even everything2 allows you to visit with your deleted posts to say your last goodbyes.  :'(

Comment: Are you saying that there's two links to the _exact same_ post, one of which is a link and the other not? Or are you asking in general for a link to deleted content through your rep page?

Comment: @JoshCaswell **one** is a link (the lower one) and the other is **not** a link at all!

Comment: That sounds like a bug.

Comment: @JoshCaswell exactly ^_^

Answer (score 2):

This is more a bug that the original downvote gets linked after its been deleted, at least that's how I think Nick Craver will see it.

See [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes/123330#comment331104_123330) by the man himself:

> Something to note on your update, if you're a 10k user those post titles are linked.

However, it would be nice to still be linked to the question itself, if the post deleted was an **answer**.

Comment: Yes but they should be linked, especially if they are my own answers!